# How to (selectively) convert array elements to a list of values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-7

Given the array below, how do I convert it to a simple list of values?

```
<cfdump var="#arguments.ServiceTextArray#">
```

**Array Elements:**

```
   1 3567_no 
   2 3584_yes 
   3 3642_yes 
   4 3643_yes 
   5 3644_no 
   6 3645_no 
   7 3646_no
```

Specifically, how do I extract values with the "yes" suffix and produce a list like this?

```
3584,3642,3643
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = "";

for (item in array)
    if (ListLast(item, "_"))
        list = listAppend(list, val(item));
```

Comment: I think they only want "yes" values.

Comment: @Leigh `yes` is a boolean value in CF, so what `listRest(item, "_")` returns will do.

Comment: @Henry lol, clever, but I think I'd be a bit frustrated if I came across that bit of code while doing maintenance.

Comment: @JakeFeasel really? Well, it's like doing `if (x == true)`, kind of unnecessary.  However, if the listRest can be some value other than `yes` or `no`, then == "yes" would be a better choice.

Comment: It is a bit like that, but you have to admit it a bit unusual to expect listRest to just pop out a boolean like that (vs. the not so unusual experience of a simple variable being evaluated as a boolean).

Comment: @JakeFeasel I found many script-based language users use boolean comparison very loosely, to keep things loose.  So I took that into my style. :)

Comment: @Henry - Neat trick. Though I am with Jake on this one. Given that it is not a simple variable, my preference is usually clarity over clever ;-) But it is a matter of personal style.

Comment: There's a big clue that a boolean is coming: *the line starts with **IF***

Comment: (Though I would do `ListLast` instead of `ListRest`, because that's less brittle.)

Comment: Sure you could figure it out, just not as intuitively. Unlike the alternatives, it is less clear what constitutes valid input within the current context: 507, 1, -4, yes or any of the above? In that regard the other approaches are more intuitive. But like I said, a lot comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Would this help? There will always be better solution than this.

```
<cfset myList = "">
<cfloop from="1" to="#Arraylen(myArray)#" index="index">

    <Cfif right(myArray[index],3) EQ "yes">
        <cfset myList = listAppend(myList, listFirst(myArray[index], '_'))>
    </Cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#myList#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Do not forget to separate the list elements with commas. Also, `listAppend` is simpler than string concatenation ie `&`

Comment: FWIW: if you want only the number portion, just split the value inside the loop: ie `myList = listAppend(myList, listFirst(myArray[index], '_'))`

Comment: I got the results like this: 3584_yes 3642_yes 3643_yes but how to convert its list only numbers..(3584,3642,3643)

Comment: Good. Do not forget to mark DG3's response as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is partly an extension to Henry answer but should be exactly what your after:

```
<cfscript>
    tmpArray = ['567_no','584_yes','3642_yes','3643_yes','3644_no','3645_no','3646_no'];
    list = "";
    for (item in tmpArray)
        if (listLast(item, "_") == "yes")
            list = listAppend(list, listFirst(item, "_"));

writeDump(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) (CF 10 only):

```
filteredArray = _.filter(arguments.ServiceTextArray, function(val) {
    return (val contains 'yes');
});

resultArray = _.map(filteredArray, function(val) {
    return left(val, 4);
});

list = arrayToList(resultArray);
```

(I created this library, BTW)

Comment: Nice one. I did not realize you could do that with CF10. Btw, is that your library? If so, you may want to add the standard affiliation disclaimer to responses [per SO rules](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added the disclaimer. Hope you find the library to be useful!